# Make Flex Fit the Users' Screen.. No matter what screen size

Tags: apache-flex

Making an Flex App. Just wondering if anyone has created something that fits automatically to the users' screen size and how I go about doing this?

One of the principle things is that I need an background image, which is obviously going to have to scale / resize to match the users screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use percentage values for the application for example.
There is also a resize-event dispatched if the size of the application changes. You can listen to it to react.

If you want to resize text regarding to the screen size, there is no smart solution as far as I know because fontSize only accepts pixel values (no em, %, etc.)